# Button created with document.createElement() to trigger onclick event, won't appear

Tags: javascript, dom

[This is my site](http://contfix.co.il) (where the relevant HTML is).

I desire to make the main menu toggled when viewport is under or equal to `768px`.

I aspire to do that only in vanilla JavaScript.

For this purpose, I wrote the following algorithm and code, which runs on DOMContentLoaded:

1. If viewport is less than or equal to `786px`, do:
2. Select the main menu and `display:none` it.
3. Create a button and give it a class.
4. Append the button to (the end of) `header`.
5. When the button is clicked, redisplay the menu.

### My code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        let menu = document.querySelector(' #menu-mainmenu ');
        return menu.style.display = 'none';

        let newButton = document.createElement('div');
        newButton.className = 'menuButton';

        let myHeader = document.querySelector('#masthead');
        myHeader.appendChild(newButton);

        newButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            return menu.style.display = 'block';
        });
    }
});
```

No errors in console in execution.

### My question:

The problem seems to be that the button doesn't get created, i.e the `createElement()` method fails (a `div` with a class `menuButton` doesn't appear in the DOM). Why would it?

Comment: Have a look at css media queries, and everything of your code should happen after domcontentloaded...

Comment: Hi made, try to use @media queries or implement bootstrap v3.3.7 with the grid system should be easy for you

Comment: You can do most of this logic using CSS media queries, always try to move away from pure jQuery logic when possible. If you want an example check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     return menu.style.display = 'none';
>
>     let newButton = document.createElement('div');
> ```

On the line before you create the element, you `return`.

`return`ing will **immediately end the function**.

Don't return there.

---

This type of task is better handled with media queries though.

Comment: I swear, it sadly didn't help... :|

Comment: I also updated the code in the question... Removing the return just didn't make any change --- Again when I fully refresh the page, the menu appears for a second and than vanishes, without any clicks from my side. That is to say, I can't even execute / utilize the addEvenetListener for onClick event.

Answer (score 1):

```
let myHeader = document.querySelector('#masthead');
```

This should get the element were we add the created one right? However theres a small problem: the site hasnt loaded yet. Im surprised that while your code looks quite ok ( wohoo, you use let ;) ) you did not notice the error in the console ( cannot get appendChild of undefined ) nor have you thought of wrapping everything in the DOMContentListener:

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    let menu = document.querySelector(' #menu-mainmenu ');
    return menu.style.display = 'none';

    let newButton = document.createElement('div');
    newButton.className = 'menuButton';

    let myHeader = document.querySelector('#masthead');
    myHeader.appendChild(newButton);

    newButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        return menu.style.display = 'block';
    });
});    
}
```

Comment: Actually I thought of wrapping all In DCL... I even tried this now but didn't work... I still don't get any error in console. Odd.

Comment: Maybe I should run the code part by part, in console.

Comment: Odd, still I didn't get this error. I updated the question with the current code I used.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp), I've added an example below, you need little jQuery code to do that.

> Observation: I've edited my answer, now it shows the main menu after you click the button.

```js
function hideButtonAndShowMenu() {
// Hides button
  document.getElementsByClassName('mobile-button')[0].style.display = 'none'   
  document.getElementsByClassName('yourMainMenuClass')[0].classList.toggle('show')
}
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .mobile-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .yourMainMenuClass:not(.show) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type='button' onclick="hideButtonAndShowMenu()" class='mobile-button' value="Don't click me please :-("> </input>
</header>

<div class='yourMainMenuClass'>
  <h2> If you are seeing this, you're not on the mobile View!</h2>
      <h3> Try resizing this window :-) </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Much thanks Artuhur. Can you please translate the jQuery code to vanilla? I desire to use only vanilla.

Comment: Just did it, hope it helps